# How to install MySQL 8.0.20 in Windows?

Tags: mysql

I have tried several suggestions from the web and I have all the prerequisites to installing MySQL. I have all Visual C++ installed on my laptop.

What could the problem be or is there something I am missing somewhere? Here is the image of the installation process with the error highlighted:

[image: Here is the image of the installation process with the error highlighted.]

Comment: Click "Try again" to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Clear all the installation paths and installed files.. again reinstall it.. Go services and see

Comment: Thank you Alwis for your help. I did all that but still problem was not solved but I sure will. Maybe I might be lucky this time.